# Generate two legends via Altair

Tags: python, python-3.x, altair

I would like to have two legends via Altair just like the picture below.
[image]

I have created the legend of "Count of actors", but I don't know how to generate the other one. My code is below:

```
plot = base.mark_circle(
   opacity=0.8,
   stroke='black',
   strokeWidth=1
).encode(
   alt.X('TYPE:O'),
   alt.Y('index:N',
          sort= movies_order
          ),
   alt.Size('count(index):Q',
   scale=alt.Scale(range=[0,4500]),
   legend=alt.Legend(title='Count of actors', symbolFillColor='white')),
   alt.Color('GENDER', legend=None)
   #complete this
).properties(
   width=350,
   height=880
```

And the chart I created is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior in Altair, but you have disabled the color legend. Change `alt.Color('GENDER', legend=None)` to `alt.Color('GENDER')`.

Here is a modifed example for the Altair gallery with two legends:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
    size='Cylinders')
```

[image]